# How to use a variable that conforms to a protocol with a specific associated type?

Tags: swift, generics

I have a question about Swift generic types

I want to make a Mapping protocol to convert one class object of another class object.

To do that I declare the protocol:

```
protocol Mapping {
    associatedtype T
    associatedtype R
    mutating func map(obj: T) -> R
}
```

Now, with the using of Mapping, I want to calculate how many users have paid me.

I am implementing a Calculator which should be able to convert User to Double

```
class Calculator<Model> {
    private let objects: [Model]
    private var mapping: Mapping // My trouble: I need Mapping<User,Double>

    init(objects: [Model], mapping: Mapping /* I need Mapping<User,Double> */) {
        self.objects = objects
        self.mapping = mapping
    }

    func calculate() {
        let numbers = self.objects.map { (obj: Model) -> Double in
            return self.mapping.map(obj)
        }
        // ... sum for numbers
    }
}
```

I want the Mapping protocol to be able to make several implementations of it, for example, ClosureMapping.

How do I declare that I need Mapping with specific classes for T and R?

I can use generic for Mapping

```
class Calculator<CalcMapping: Mapping, Model> where CalcMapping.T == Model, CalcMapping.R == Double {
    private let objects: [Model]
    private var mapping: CalcMapping

    init(objects: [Model], mapping: CalcMapping) {
        self.objects = objects
        self.mapping = mapping
    }

    func calculate() {
        let numbers = self.objects.map { (obj: Model) -> Double in
            return self.mapping.map(obj)
        }
        // ... sum for numbers
    }
}
```

but so I can’t change the mapping strategy.
I always need to specify a specific mapping strategy in declaring a variable

```
class Manager {
    private let calculator: Calculator<MyMapping, User>

    func init() {
        let users = [User]() // ...
        self.calculator = Calculator(objects: users, mapping: MyMapping)
        // I can't create calculator with another Mapping, eg MappingMock
    }

}
```

### Update

I was able to specify protocol requirements with associative types through the use of an abstract class.
I have two variables that are declared the same, but I use different mapping implementations.

```
let yearPurchaseMapping = UserClosureMapping { (user: User) -> Double in
    user.yearPurchases()
}
let monthPurchaseMapping = UserMonthPurchaseMapping()

let yearCalc: Calculator<AbstractMapping<User,Double>, User, Double> = Calculator(mapping: yearPurchaseMapping)
let monthCalc: Calculator<AbstractMapping<User,Double>, User, Double> = Calculator(mapping: monthPurchaseMapping)
```

my gist https://gist.github.com/chchrn/0eff4681bf1f9f5312ce7b862c168cc8

Comment: This is not possible as of now in `Swift`. You can only use such protocol in your generic type similar to `Calculator` where associated type are defined and understood by the compiler. In any concrete declaration where associated types are not known, compiler won't allow that.

Comment: Thanks, but I need concrete `Calculator`  where `Model == User`, but I need use various Classes implemented Mapping with specific associated types `T=User, R =Double`. `Mapping` is a Strategy for converting a `User` -> `Double`. And I want to specify only conditions for associated types in Calculator, `T == User, R == Double`